# react-native-webview not works on android (RN 0.60.5)

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-webview

I create new react-native app (react native version 0.60.5 and add react-native-webview. App works on iOS. But on Android not works.

```sh
react-native init WebViewApp
```

```sh
cd WebViewApp
```

```sh
yarn add react-native-webview
```

```sh
cd ios
```

```sh
pod install
```

```sh
cd ..
```

I create easy code in App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.body}>
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: 'https://example.com' }}
          style={styles.body}
        />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  body: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

It's works on iOS.
Not work on Android

```sh
react-native run-android
```

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 876 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-webview
>   :react-native-webview:reactNativeAndroidRoot /Users/clark/Documents/react-native/examples/WebViewApp/node_modules/react-native/android
>
> Task :app:installDebug
>   09:29:21 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
>   09:29:21 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   09:29:21 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_API_Q(AVD) - 10' for app:debug
>   09:29:21 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   09:29:21 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
>   09:29:21 D/ddms: Reading file permision of /Users/clark/Documents/react-native/examples/WebViewApp/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk as: rw-r--r--
>   09:29:21 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   09:29:22 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   09:29:22 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   09:29:22 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
>   09:29:22 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
>   09:29:22 V/ddms: execute: returning
>   Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
46 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 44 up-to-date
<-------------> 0% WAITING

> IDLE
>   IDLE
>   IDLE
>   IDLE
>   info Connecting to the development server...
>   adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted
>   warn Failed to connect to development server using "adb reverse": Command failed: /Users/clark/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
>   info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
>   Starting: Intent { cmp=com.webviewapp/.MainActivity }
>   Igors-MacBook-Pro:WebViewApp clark$